# MPI program only executed once in slurm script

Tags: c, mpi, hostname, slurm

I have tried both `MPI_Get_processor_name()` and `gethostname()` to print all of the nodes that I've used. But it only returns the name of the first node! Could anyone let me know what is the problem and how I can get the name of all nodes?

```
//testMPI.c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d"
           " out of %d processors\n", processor_name, world_rank, world_size);}


    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I've used a job script to run it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=MPI-host
#SBATCH --account=123
#SBATCH --time=00:02:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3900M
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH --nodes=4
#SBATCH --output=./output-mpi-host-test2.out

module load intel/2015.3
module load openmpi.intel/1.8.6

cp $(pwd)/$1 $SCRATCH
cd $SCRATCH

./$1
```

Comment: Could you please attach your code using the above functions?

Comment: I've edited and put the code.

Comment: ... Please also include the actual output and how it exactly from the expected one. Though I guess I know how it looks like.

Comment: I took the liberty to make the title more generic so it can be found easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI programs need to be launched using `mpiexec` or a batch-system specific command, in the case of SLURM `srun`. Replace your last line in the script with

```
srun ./$1
```

Note: it takes the parameters automatically from the job script. For plain `mpiexec`, you should provide the number of processes and other parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zulan. It helped :)

Comment: Hi @Sarah if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.